# Change selection tool coordinates from easting/northing to lat/long in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

While right clicking in QGIS to copy coordinates, IT is showing coordinates in northing and easting instead of Lat-Long though I have tried changing CRS and related settings but it's not working.

Comment: Open Lat Lon settings (in toolbar, wrench icon) and in Capture tab change CRS/Projection of captured coordinate to your desired coordinate system.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Thanks but your answer is for lat lon plugin. I'm asking about direct right click on map.